# AssertionError running Llama 2 locally in Python

Tags: python, jupyter, large-language-model, llama

I am running a Jupyter [notebook](https://swharden.com/static/2023/07/30/llama2-quickstart.ipynb.zip) for the purpose of running Llama 2 locally in Python. I downloaded the 7B parameter Llama 2 model to the root folder of my `D:` drive. I installed version 0.2.6 of Llama 2 using `!pip install llama-cpp-python`. I am running into an error when I try to initialize the model, however.

**Code block:**

```
MODEL_Q8_0 = Llama(
    model_path="D:/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
    n_ctx=2048)
```

**Error:**

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\btayl\Downloads\llama2-quickstart.ipynb\llama2-quickstart.ipynb Cell 5 line 1
----> 1 MODEL_Q8_0 = Llama(
      2     model_path="D:/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
      3     n_ctx=2048)

File d:\Programs\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\llama_cpp\llama.py:340, in Llama.__init__(self, model_path, seed, n_ctx, n_batch, n_gpu_layers, main_gpu, tensor_split, rope_freq_base, rope_freq_scale, low_vram, mul_mat_q, f16_kv, logits_all, vocab_only, use_mmap, use_mlock, embedding, n_threads, last_n_tokens_size, lora_base, lora_path, numa, verbose, **kwargs)
    336     with suppress_stdout_stderr():
    337         self.model = llama_cpp.llama_load_model_from_file(
    338             self.model_path.encode("utf-8"), self.params
    339         )
--> 340 assert self.model is not None
    342 if verbose:
    343     self.ctx = llama_cpp.llama_new_context_with_model(self.model, self.params)

AssertionError:
```

I read a [GitHub help page](https://github.com/abetlen/llama-cpp-python/issues/643) asserting an error with GGML files and newer versions of Llama 2 but downgrading to 0.1.78 did not fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded a GGUF model from [Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-GGUF) and replaced the model path with that file. This resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you do the download to get the .bin file?

Comment: You do not want to use a bin file. You want to use a gguf file. I got the bin file from this blog: https://swharden.com/blog/2023-07-29-ai-chat-locally-with-python/